# Custom UISegmented Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I acheive this in iOS UISegmentedControl (Objective-C)

I want to show rounded selection for selected segment control.

[image]

Any Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol) has a section for [customization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol#1653545).

Summary as follows:
All you have to do is provide divider images for different state combinations. That means you need to provide 3 images in all for following states:

1. Image between two unselected segments
2. Image between segment selected on the left and unselected on the right
3. Image between segment selected on the right and unselected on the left

Code as follows:

**Objective-C**

```
// Image between two unselected segments.
[mySegmentedControl setDividerImage:image1 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                  rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:barMetrics];
// Image between segment selected on the left and unselected on the right.
[mySegmentedControl setDividerImage:image1 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                  rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:barMetrics];
// Image between segment selected on the right and unselected on the right.
[mySegmentedControl setDividerImage:image1 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                  rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:barMetrics];
```

**Swift**

```
    // Image between two unselected segments.
    mySegmentedControl.setDividerImage(myImage, forLeftSegmentState: UIControlState.Normal,
                                       rightSegmentState: UIControlState.Normal, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)

    // Image between segment selected on the left and unselected on the right.
    mySegmentedControl.setDividerImage(myImage, forLeftSegmentState: UIControlState.Selected,
                                       rightSegmentState: UIControlState.Normal, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)

    // Image between segment selected on the right and unselected on the left.
    mySegmentedControl.setDividerImage(myImage, forLeftSegmentState: UIControlState.Normal,
                                       rightSegmentState: UIControlState.Selected, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Here is a [post](http://smnh.me/customizing-appearance-of-uisegmentedcontrol/) that explains how to achieve this.

If you see the linked post those are 3 images. Attaching the screenshot for reference:
[image]

Comment: can you post some sample images for image1 ?